# installing pyobjc on mac osx 10.9

Tags: python-2.7, xcode5, osx-mavericks, setuptools, pyobjc

I'm trying to download pyobjc on my mac, which runs on 10.9.3. I've tried using easy_install, pip, and manual install. I have setuptools installed with Xcode 5.

When I use easy_install, pip, or manual install I get the error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_install_lib' right before it quits, along with other errors before this. For easy_install I type the following line in the terminal:

```
easy_install -U pyobjc
```

and for pip I use:

```
pip -U pyobjc
```

for manual install I use:

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Are you using the pre-installed Mavericks python or a third party? (homebrew, macports, manual etc.)

Comment: I downloaded python manually I believe.

Comment: @acannon828 I just tried doing that several times, including uninstalling and reinstalling pip, but I get the same error as before.

Answer (score 3):

I too was having this problem, also described [here](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/issue/86/installation-problems-with-setuptools-36). It seems to be a problem with setuptools. I was able to successfully install PyObjC by reinstalling setuptools first, i.e.:

```
$> sudo pip uninstall setuptools
$> pip install setuptools
$> pip install pyobjc
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was fixed in pyobjc 2.5.1.